# Using a Generic Value Object in a DDD application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ddd

I am writing this question in the context of a DDD application.  I found this code online on a number of blogs etc e.g. [here](https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/ValueObject.cs)  and [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/).

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> 
         where T : ValueObject<T> 
     { 
        protected abstract IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents(); 


         public override bool Equals(object obj) 
       { 
            var valueObject = obj as T; 


             if (ReferenceEquals(valueObject, null)) 
                return false; 


            return EqualsCore(valueObject); 
       } 


         private bool EqualsCore(ValueObject<T> other) 
         { 
             return GetEqualityComponents().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityComponents()); 
         }  

         public override int GetHashCode() 
         { 
             return GetEqualityComponents() 
                 .Aggregate(1, (current, obj) => current * 23 + (obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0)); 
         } 


         public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> a, ValueObject<T> b) 
        { 
             if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null)) 
                 return true; 


             if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null)) 
                 return false; 


             return a.Equals(b); 
         } 


         public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> a, ValueObject<T> b) 
         { 
             return !(a == b); 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Every Value Object in my application inherits from it.  It means the methods like: `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are dealt with implicitly.  The main problem I see arises if I want to add a collection e.g. array as a member of a Value Object - in this scenario the generic value object `.Equals` will not behave as expected as it cannot deal with collections.

Therefore:

1. Can this class be tweaked to deal with collections?
2. Are there any other downfalls with this approach?
3. Is it advisable not to use a generic value class when developing a DDD application?

Comment: refactor `EqualsCore` to be `protected virtual` to allow derived classes with generic collection arguments to be able to override and determine equality themselves.

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks.  I believe that is what the Blogger here has done: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/08/04/representing-a-collection-as-a-value-object/.  If you post an answer, then I will give some credit.

Comment: I have read many of those articles before. You should base your base value object on the one provided [here](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/01/03/value-objects-explained/) by the same author. I understand what you are trying to achieve with `GetEqualityComponents` but that appears to be premature optimization to me.

Comment: @Nkosi, do you use the class in your link in a live application? I am trying to completely isolate my domain model by introducing a data model to map to the ORM.

Comment: I have had some time to review the git hub link you posted and realize it is a more recent version of the one I suggested (*it is the same author by the way*). I have also been able to figure out that you can deal with collections via the `GetEqualityComponents` implementation by using the collections enumeration for the components.

Comment: @Nkosi, are you able to show how to use GetEqualityComponents in an answer?

Comment: I was in the middle of doing that when you posted your comment. Please review the example I provided.

Comment: I know the term "domain driven design". What is the "DDD application" though?

Comment: @Igor Soloydenko, it is just my terminology.  It does not mean anything conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code in your example along with the following article for reference

[Representing a collection as a Value Object](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/08/04/representing-a-collection-as-a-value-object/)

Lets start with refactoring the City value object to use the improved `ValueObject`

```
public sealed class City : ValueObject<City> {

    public string Name { get; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; }

    public City(string name, bool isEnabled) {
        Name = name;
        IsEnabled = isEnabled;
    } 

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents() {
        yield return Name; 
        yield return IsEnabled;
    }
}
```

Note how `GetEqualityComponents` was implemented. Reflection could also have been used to enumerate the properties as needed

```
return this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(this, null);
```

There is room for improvement above and I will leave that as an exercise.

For collections, the `GetEqualityComponents` allows for a simplified approach of returning the items used to check equality.

```
public class CityList : ValueObject<CityList>, IEnumerable<City> {

    private List<City> _cities { get; }

    public CityList(IEnumerable<City> cities) {
        _cities = cities.ToList();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents() {
        return this.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
    }

    public IEnumerator<City> GetEnumerator() {
        return _cities.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that since the collection already implements `IEnumerable` one simple needs to return the desired enumeration that will be used to calculate equality.

`GetEqualityComponents()` proves to be a very convenient approach and really does improve and simplify how the `ValueObject` can be implemented. I initially though it to be a premature optimization attempt but having taken some time to review its potential I have changed my initial view of its function.

**UPDATE** from comments about the potential of using reflection.:

> The use of reflection automates and simplifies a repetitive task with
>   a minor performance trade off. Caching the property/field info could
>   help a little but I personally have had no issues with it performance
>   wise. Also using reflection grabs all while using the yield like in
>   the example you get to be selective of which ones to use for equality.
>   You can make an extension method to get the best of both worlds and
>   have options.

```
public static class ValueObjectExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses reflection to extract all public properties from the target value object
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<object> GetComponents<T>(this ValueObject<T> target)
        where T : ValueObject<T> {
        return target.GetType().GetProperties().Select(propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(target, null));
    }
}
```

and used like

```
protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents() {
   return this.GetComponents(); //<-- calling extension method
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will test this in the morning at get back to you.  Would you use this value object in your systems? - I am trying to establish whether the authors have published a thought exercise or practical tips.  I am working towards a completely isolated domain model (with a data model that maps to orm) if that has any bearing.

Comment: @w0051977 I have used this before in slightly different forms to suit my specific needs. I used the same articles to get a better understanding of the concept. The quoted author also states that they have used this on many projects but he tends to focus more on apply functional programming and adapting it in c#.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by equalscore (v equals I mean).  What is meant by "core"?

Comment: @w0051977 what do you mean? Can you clarify your last comment.

Comment: please look at the method name in my original post.  Is there a reason it is called: equalscore? (what does the 'core' mean).

Comment: @w0051977 it is simply a sub method. When overriding `Equals` instead of placing all the functionality in that method itself the author extracted the core functionality of determining equality into its own method `EqualsCore`. It is basically a naming pattern.

Comment: why EqualsCore instead of EqualsHelloWorld or EqualsDomain.  What does the Core actually mean? I realise this may sound a bit pedantic.  I will probably be asked when someone else looks at my code.

Comment: @w0051977 if you look at the original version of the value object you will see that the same was done for `GetHashcode`. As in `GetHashcodeCore`

Comment: I see that.  I just wander why the word: 'Core' was used?

Comment: @w0051977 It represents the *core/main/primary* functionality of the method. The core is the inner most part of something. So would seem appropriate to call the inner most workings of a method its core. This is all a matter is naming preferences. You could rename it to what ever you like.

Comment: One more thing (before I accept).  What do you think of the code in OP instead of this: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/ (using reflection to get the values to compare - which you briefly refer to in your answer).

Comment: @w0051977 The use of reflection automates and simplifies a repetitive task with a minor performance trade off. Caching the property/field info could help a little but I personally have had no issues with it performance wise. Also using reflection grabs all while using the yield like in the example you get to be selective of which ones to use for equality. You can make an extension method to get the best of both worlds and have options.

Comment: +1 for the reference to an extension method.  If you could provide an example then that would be great.

Comment: @w0051977 now seriously, how difficult is it for you to encapsulate this `return this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(this, null);` into a generic extension method.

Comment: I asked because I didn't (and still don't) understand why this should be a generic extension method (rather than a regular method).  I will have to do some reading up - I don't have a great deal of experience with extension methods.

Comment: @w0051977 check update

Comment: May I ask why it is an extension method and not a regular method in the ValueObject<T> class? I am reading up as we speak so may know soon (and may not).  Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977 preference. you could include it as a member if you wish.

Comment: I guess there are no specific benefits of one or the other? - this is the last question.

Comment: @w0051977 at this point is purely a matter of preference.